# how to disable error messaging android

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, settings

Problem:
I am working with custom UI, now. There are some threads inside a program. Sometimes system shows message that my app has stopped. But it's false in my case. My app instantly restores itself and keeps working so everything is just fine.

Question:
Is there a way to disable any system messages appearing?

I am new in android and will be really grateful for some advice.

(edit)

Well so i found the following. App crushes on start after it was "closed" by hardware "<-- Back" button. Not every time only sometimes. When i select it in menu of opened apps once more it opens normally and runs just fine. Is there a way to remove that "crush" message? sure i do understand that app has crushed and its not good at all.

Comment: "Sometimes system shows message that my app has stopped. But it's false in my case" -- and your proof of this is... what, exactly?

Comment: "My app instantly restores itself.." That implies it is crashing, but the OS is recovering, therefore you should fix your code. Note, I have noticed that newer Androids are able to recover while older ones are not. Keep that in mind.

Comment: well so i found the following. App crushes on start after it was "closed" by hardware "<-- Back" button. Not every time only sometimes. When i select it in menu of opened apps once more it opens normally and runs just fine. Is there a way to remove that "crush" message? sure i do understand that app has crushed and its not good at all.

Comment: the reason of crush is that one of 3 Canvas i use is Null. I have 3 Canvas for 3 different SurfaceViews on one layout - all of them are onDraw() by one thread. They work just fine, but that crush do appear sometimes.